# Differential equation with Euler's method

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods

Unfortunately from online classes i missed this lesson and now have an assignment question that has to be solved however im struggling to work this one out! Any help and answer would be appreciated thankyou. Im very willing to learn how to solve this problem as its going to be part of my job. This forum is my last hope of learning and working this out. It would be very much appreciated.

Regards!

Here is the original task:

> The differential equation of a circuit is:
>   $$0.045\frac{dv}{dt} = 15t^2 - v,$$
>   where $v$ is the voltage. When $t = 0\; v = 1$.
>
> (a) Use Euler's method to obtain a numerical solution for the range $0 >\leq t \leq 0.5$ with intervals of $0.01$.
>
> (b) Plot the graph of $v$ against $t$ for $0 \leq t \leq 0.5$. Briefly explain the graph.

Comment: Your enthusiasm is welcome, but please show it in a more concrete way by giving us some details about what you've attempted. Have you tried reading about [Euler's method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_method)?

Comment: do you have a program that implement the eludes method?

Answer (score 1):

euler's method for the initial value problem $$\frac{dv}{dt} = f(t, v) = \frac1{0.045} (15t^2 - v), v = v_0=1 \text{ at } t = 0.$$ is

$$v_{n+1} = v_n+hf(nh, v_n) \text{ where }v_n \simeq v(nh), v(0) = v_0, h = 0.01 $$

for example, $$v_1 = 1+0.01 \times \frac1{0.045}(0-1)=0.7777$$

i did this on my ti-$83.$  here is what i got:

$\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|}\hline
t & 0.00 &0.01 & 0.02 & 0.03 &0.04 &0.05\\ \hline
v & 1.00 &0.7777 &0.6053 & 0.4721 &0.3702 &0.2536 \\ \hline\end{array}$

Comment: Thankyou Abel, this makes sense and looks correct! I have also now succesfully plotted the graph!! Result! I have put another question up im unsure of and have started if you can help with that.      Best Regards!